# Pass values from activity to Fragment by bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

in my fragment the bundle is always null

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putString("itemname", "hello");
        beaconListFragment=new BeaconListFragment();
        beaconListFragment.setArguments(args);

        //i don't know if this is needed or not, i tried with and without it
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, beaconListFragment,"tag").commit();
    }

    ...
    ..
    .
```

BeaconListFragment

```
public class BeaconListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();


        //bundle is always null
        if (bundle != null) {
            String link = bundle.getString("itemname");

        }
    }
    ...
    ..
    .
```

most examples seem like this but i can't understand where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should read the data in onCreate  not onActivityCreated

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null)
    {
        String link = bundle.getString("itemname");
    }

}
```

Comment: Bundle bundle = getArguments();  is null into the onCreate method as well :-(

Answer (score 0):

For fragment there is a method like **setArguments()** in that method you can pass bundle object.

And in the fragment class you can access that bundle by **getArguments()**.

In above way you can pass params

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statements in the Fragment. Looks like you are mixing 2 types: one from SDK and another from support library. Make sure to use any one.

Your Fragment inherits from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Your import statements are not visible in the code here. If your import statement has `android.app.Fragment`, then remove that line and try.